# How do I get Copy & Paste to work like Cut & Paste with formulas in Excel 2007?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function, cut-and-paste

Excel 2007 when I Cut & Paste `=K62` to a new worksheet and I get `=Scenario!K62`. When I copy and Paste it I get `=REF!`.

How can I get Copy & Paste to work the same way as Cut & Paste does?

Comment: Have you tried this MS Office Support Article - [Move or Copy Formula](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/move-or-copy-a-formula-HP010102342.aspx)?

Comment: Yar, but that is talking about keeping things in the same worksheet.  This is moving to a new worksheet, when I cut & paste it auto adds in the reference link "Scenario!" when I Copy&Paste it just turns into REF!.  I don't want to go back and add in "Scenario!" to every equation I need to copy but I don't want to cut as I still need them in that current worksheet.

Comment: copy, right click, paste special, paste special, Formulas, OK
Have you tried this? Beware, when you want to do something like this, sometimes you need the sheets to be identical, for instance if H24 = D9, you'll want to paste formula in H24 on the other sheet, because the reference is relative. Try using H24 = $D$9

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste brings over the relative references in a formula to the new sheet.

For example, say you have the formula `= A2 + G5` in cell E2.

What get copied over to the new worksheet is "take the cell four columns to the left of the cell the formula is in and add it to the cell two columns to the right and three cells down.

If you copy the formula into a cell in the new sheet that puts one of those references "off the sheet", cell A2, for example, you get the REF! error.

Cut and paste, on the other hand, preserves the absolute references in the old sheet when you copy it to the new sheet.

This is the built-in behavior for both these actions.

Comment: Is there any possible way to make the Copy & Paste function preserve the absolute references?

Comment: You can cut and paste the formula into the new sheet, put the cell into edit mode (F2 key), highlight and copy the formula (still in the new sheet), and paste it back into the old sheet. There are also more elaborate ways to accomplish this for a range of formulas (see [here](http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/making_an_exact_copy_of_a_range_of_formulas/), for example, but it's all a bit clunky. I assume it would be possible to program a way in VBA, but I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out a (not so great) workaround:

1. Make a copy of the sheet that you want to copy from
2. Cut the cells (instead of copy)
3. Paste
4. Delete the copy of the sheet (which is now missing the information)

As long as you are not also referencing those cells elsewhere, it should work!

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste in excel changes the Cell Row number when you move within sheet

Eg                 L62 contain formula K62
 If pasted in L63 formula change K63
If pasted in M62 formula change L62

and  to fix the cell you have to use $

Eg                 L62 contain formula $K$62
 If pasted in L63 formula change $K$62
If pasted in M62 formula change $K$62

sign to fix column and rows or row but when you move within sheets it changes reference and it gives error of REF because its can't calculate or guess how many rows or columns you moved

I don't think you can change the copy and paste functioning except by VBA programming

Cut and paste cuts formula without changing column row number within sheet or other sheet

If you want to copy FORMULA ONLY without changing cell row or column number while dragging or copying

1. Just press F2 in cell
2. Select the formula text or address bar
3. Copy the formula
4. Paste the formula in other sheet in any cell

Another way

1. Just click cell
2. Copy the cell
3. Select the destination cell another sheet
4. Right click the cell
5. Click on paste special
6. Select paste formula

If you want to copy FORMULA  without changing cell row or column number while dragging or copying

Eg                 L62 contain formula K62

1. Just click cell L62
2. Press f2 button to edit
3. Change formula to =$K$62
4. Right click the cell  L62 and copy
5. Click on another sheet and paste on the sheet cell

Here I am providing links which may help you to find some more ways or options with picture

[Preserve Cell References when Copying a Formula in Excel](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://helpdeskgeek.com/office-tips/preserve-cell-references-when-copying-a-formula-in-excel/amp/&ved=2ahUKEwiv6MGsoeDnAhVgH7cAHdrkCCEQFjAFegQIDhAK&usg=AOvVaw0FRYpyXRhfd86XIYEi-gCY&ampcf=1&cshid=1582207053131)

[How to copy formula in Excel: down a column, without changing references, etc](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2016/01/20/copy-formula-excel/&ved=2ahUKEwiv6MGsoeDnAhVgH7cAHdrkCCEQFjAOegQIARAB&usg=AOvVaw1swOnAj2KRvTP0BXXJf68f&cshid=158220728083)

> if you find it useful then vote or accept the answer you may ask more questions if have any problem

Comment: Please read [How to reference material written by others](https://superuser.com/help/referencing). You must block quote text that has been written by some else. See [Markdown help](https://superuser.com/editing-help).